# How can I get GET/ parameters from client to server using express?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, parameters

I am trying to make a web using react plus NODE.js server and express but I cannot get parameters of GET function on my client side(localhost:3000), when I try to do it on my server api (localhost:5000) it works, on the other side on my client side I cannot get the url/params from my browser url

Server code:

```
 const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const pgp = require('pg-promise')(/* options */)
    const app = express();
    const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })
    
    app.get('/aboutus',urlencodedParser, (req, result) => {
      console.log(req.query);
      result.send( req.query.id);
    });
    
    app.get('/1',urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.url)
      res.send( req.url);
    })
```

client:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class AboutUs extends Component {
  state = {
    about: '',
    about1: '',
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/aboutus')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            about: result,
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
          about:  error
          });
        }
      )
    fetch('/1')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      (result) => {
        this.setState({
          about1: result,
        });
      },
    )
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{'abc' + JSON.stringify(this.state.about)}</p>
        <p>{'def ' + JSON.stringify(this.state.about1)}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AboutUs;
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong, when I access url like `localhost:5000/aboutus?id=abcd` then the `res.send` outputs "abcd", but when I access `loclhost:3000/aboutus?id=efgs` I don't get any parameters. Maybe I have to do it other way, but I couldn`t find any way how to do it.
The api's work, for example when i send req.url I can display it, I just cant get the parameters:
[no params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96BDD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you previously setted any proxy on your react project? if you haven't, then you should specify the full path to your server api when fetching the data.

fetch('http://localhost:5000/aboutus') instead of just /aboutus.

Also, make sure you are not having any cors error, that could be rejecting the request when calling it using fetch.

Comment: Proxy is set in json: "proxy": "localhost:5000", the get method works right sending data to the react client, I did some database querries and also displayed them, with the whole url in fetch it does not work, even when I send req.url, I can display it in react, but I get only the url which I use in fetch, when I add any parameters it like ignores it, or I don't know what it does.